# Bike start in gear without pressing clutch

Tags: motorcycle

Clutch is working fine, but my bike start in gear without pressing clutch.
What can be done to avoid this?

Comment: What is the make and model? Is there a clutch Switch? If so check it's not stuck

Comment: it is not clear to me what you ask here,most bikes can start whitout pressing clutch as long as your bike is in neutral.is this question about a problem where you can engage the starter even if your bike is in gear?